# Why is my file a different size after I upload it and convert to byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, arrays, memorystream

I am using the following code to get a byte array out of an HttPostedFileBase object

```
byte[] mobileAppByteArray = default(byte[]);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  httpPostedFileObject.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
  mobileAppByteArray = ms.GetBuffer();
}
```

The original size of the httpPostedFileObject is 3191KB, but after the above conversion and saving it to disk, the file size is 4096KB

I understand that the default buffer size for `CopyTo` is 4096, but even if I change the buffer size to 1024, the result is the same: file size is 4096KB.

How can I change my code so that my file remains as 3191KB after I save to disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) will return the entire underlying buffer, not just the portion of it that's been filled with bytes from the input stream. Try using the [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) method instead:

```
mobileAppByteArray = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Just one more thing: the linked doc seems to have a warning about ToArray `however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in memory.` Is that a problem? And is there any way around that?  GetBuffer gets a reference to the undelying buffer, so is there a way to get a reference to the "used" part of the buffer?

Comment: @TheFabledOne Not really. `CopyTo` will copy just the used portion of the array, and the `Length` property will tell you how much of the array is used, but in both cases you'd probably need to change how you're using the memory stream. If you want to get an array that just represents the used portion of the buffer, `ToArray` is it.